# Oracle - Inconsistent drop column behavior on a table with COMPRESS BASIC

Tags: oracle, compression, oracle19c, drop

**How can I determine in *advance* if a table with `COMPRESS BASIC` will or will not generate the ORA-39726 error?**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed May 31 08:37:58 2023
Version 19.14.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected.

SQL>column banner_full format A71
SQL>select banner_full from v$version
  2  /
BANNER_FULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.19.0.0.0
```

Given I have a table with `COMPRESS BASIC` that was created recently whose had a column added to it when I drop the new column then I am not receiving *"ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on compressed tables"* and the drop column is being silently converted into a `SET UNUSED COLUMN`.

This behavior is different than what Tom [posted](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:69076630635645) on AskTom, albeit back in 2006, but the 19c docs don't seem to suggest things have changed in this regard:

- 19c [drop_column_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20unused%20a%20column%20from%20a%20table%20that%20uses%20COMPRESS%20BASIC%2C%20but%20you%20cannot%20drop%20the%20column.) SQL reference.

> "You can set unused a column from a table that uses COMPRESS BASIC, but you cannot drop the column."

- 19c table_compression clauses [Restrictions on Table Compression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20drop%20a%20column%20from%20a%20table%20that%20uses%20COMPRESS%20BASIC%2C%20although%20you%20can%20set%20such%20a%20column%20as%20unused.) SQL reference.

> "You cannot drop a column from a table that uses COMPRESS BASIC, although you can set such a column as unused."

**Why am I not getting the ORA-39726 error in 19c?**

- [21c db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TVbJc4kM)
- [18c db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G2Optces)

Note: To actually drop the column, I then have to `MOVE NOCOMPRESS` the table and then `DROP UNUSED COLUMNS`.

```
SQL>create table t_new compress as select * from all_users
  2  /
Table created.

SQL>alter table t_new add x number
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>alter table t_new drop column x
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>column table_name format A10
SQL>select * from user_unused_col_tabs
  2  /
TABLE_NAME      COUNT
---------- ----------
T_NEW               1

SQL>alter table t_new nocompress
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>alter table t_new drop unused columns
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>select * from user_unused_col_tabs
  2  /
TABLE_NAME      COUNT
---------- ----------
T_NEW               1

SQL>alter table t_new move nocompress
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>alter table t_new drop unused columns
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>select * from user_unused_col_tabs
  2  /
no rows selected

SQL>alter table t_new compress
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>drop table t_new
  2  /
Table dropped.

SQL>
```

However, if I repeat this in 19c with a table that was created previously (likely when the database was 12c), then I do get the *ORA-39726* error.
Furthermore, I don't actually have to `MOVE NOCOMPRESS` the table, I can instead simply alter the table's data dictionary to `NOCOMPRESS` and then the `DROP COLUMN` is now allowed and actually drops the column (not just a silent `UNUSED`).
This too seems like it has changed as the `NOCOMPRESS` only applies to future direct-path inserts, so I don't understand how I can get away with *only* doing a data dictionary change without actually moving and uncompressing those table blocks.

Note: I cannot recreate the *ORA-39726* when dropping columns with newly created tables in 19c; I can only recreate it within 19c using tables that were originally created prior to 19c.
Hence, the distinction of `t_new` and `t_old` table names in the examples.
I don't know how to show what Oracle version was in effect when a table was created (perhaps some block version in a block header) or even if it is relevant to this question.

**How come a data dictionary `NOCOMPRESS` table alter is sufficient, and do I not have to `MOVE NOCOMPRESS` the table as previously required [18c db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yj0kO9au)?**

```
-- In the same 19c environment as above, but using a table created when the database was 12c.
SQL>alter table t_old add x number
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>update t_old set x = 1
  2  /
3845 rows updated.

SQL>alter table t_old drop column x
  2  /
alter table t_old drop column x
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on compressed tables

SQL>alter table t_old nocompress
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>alter table t_old drop column x
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>select * from user_unused_col_tabs
  2  /
no rows selected

SQL>alter table t_old compress
  2  /
Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Great question. I'll be interested in the answer.